# Angular 2 update child component's class list from parent

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I'm new to Angular 2 and I need some help with the following issue.
I have a parent and a nested, child component:

```
// The Parent:
import { Component, ViewChild } from 'angular2/core';
import {Preloader} from 'components/preloader/preloader';


@Component({
  selector: 'console',
  providers: [Preloader],
  directives: [Preloader],
  templateUrl: 'components/console/console.html'
})


export class Console {
  @ViewChild(Preloader) preloader: Preloader;

  constructor(preloader: Preloader) {
    this.preloader = preloader;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.preloader.showConsole();
  }
}


// ...and the Child
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'preloader',
  template: `
    <div [ngClass]="style"></div>
  `
})


export class Preloader {
  constructor() {
    this.style = {
      fullscreen: true,
      done: false
    };
  }

  showConsole() {
    // this is not working:
    this.style.done = true;
  }
}
```

I'd like to set both variables in `style` object to `true` when the parent component is fully mounted. That actually happends, but in the Preloader's template I see only `fullscreen` class even after `showConsole` method was called and `style.done` was set to `true`.

`console.html` template is just like this:

```
<div class="main-window">
  <preloader></preloader>
</div>
```

Comment: it seems like you have name conflict.

Comment: Why are you using an angular version THAT old? probably like 15 versions behind :P

Comment: @Jesus You were right: I've updated A2 version, but unfortunately, that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out!
The problem was in the communication between two components. First of all this is how I should have pass the data in the template:

```
<div class="main-window">
  <preloader [start]='showConsole'></preloader>
</div>
```

But, the most important thing, it also requires to specificate input variables in the child `@Component` like this:

```
@Component({
  inputs:   ['start'],
  selector: 'preloader',
  template: `<div [ngClass]="style"></div>`
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tested and your solution is working without any problem.

But if you still say `fullscreen` class remains same then you can consider below solution,

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        this.preloader.showConsole();
    },0)        
 }
```

```
showConsole() {
    this.style.fullscreen = false;   //<<<===added.
    this.style.done = true;
 }
```

Comment: It's really weird. Still not forking for me. The thing is if I try to update `style` from the child, with a `setTimeout` in the constructor, for example: `setTimeout(() => { this.style.done = true; }, 1000);` it adds the second class.

Comment: Oh yes you need to use setTimeout. yes you are right.

Comment: But have a look at updated answer. I used setTimeout in parent component.

Comment: I've debugged your solution, but it's the same: the object is updated, but not the class list in template. I'm afraid it's something with data binding in the child component.

Comment: again i updated my answer and updated `this.style.fullscreen = false;` this line.